# Replica set initialization with a script

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Im trying to automate sharding/replication a bit.
For that purpose I wrote a very simple script:

```
print("Init replica set")
rs.initiate()
print("Adding a new node")
rs.add("[not a local host]:7776")
quit()
```

It inits the set, but fails to add the node. Any idea why?

Btw, when i just connect and paste the whole script it works.

**EDIT**:
When I run add command with --eval i get

> JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: no error at all, cause nothing is output during scrip execution except for my print commands, just the second node is not initialized...

Comment: Are both nodes set with the same replSet in their respective config files?

Comment: yes, it is just the script which does seem to run